# JQuery animate scrollTop Container

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

**I have the following snippet to scroll my form to the first error:**

```
$('html,body').stop().delay(500).animate({scrollTop: $errors.filter(":first").offset().top -30},'slow');
```

**The full block at the end of my jquery validation code looks like the following. If there is an error upon submission, it scrolls the form to the first error.**

```
var $errors = $(".mcError");
if($errors.size() > 0){
    if(settings.mcScrollToError){
        $('html,body').stop().delay(500).animate({scrollTop: $errors.filter(":first").offset().top -30},'slow');
    }
    return false;
}
else{
    mcResponse('', false);
    return true;
}
```

**However, if I replace the `$('html,body')` with the name of a container element such as a div class `$('.myDivClass')`, it doesn't seem to work well. It just scrolls to random places.**

**The css of the container element looks like this (so you know what I mean):**

```
.mcModalWrap1{
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
padding:50px;
background-image:url(images/overlay.png);
overflow:auto;
z-index:999;
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.offset()`:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the document.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/offset/*

You want to use `.position()` to get the relative position::

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the offset parent.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/position*

For example:

```
$('.myDivClass').stop().delay(500).animate({ scrollTop: ($errors.filter(":first").position().top -30) },'slow');
```

Comment: I seem to get the same results.

Comment: Could you post a link so I could see the behavior?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't upload the files. I will accept the answer though. Thank you!